# Debug servlets with eclipse (running resin)

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, debugging, resin

I am using eclipse (Java EE edition) to write Java servlets and I would like to utilize the debugging functionality.  However, I was reading the tutorial to set this up and when I got to the stage the choose a "Server Runtime Environment", I got stuck.  I am using Resin, which does not appear to be in the list of available server runtimes.  Is there any way to get around this?  Is the debugging unusable with Resin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run your server  in a remote debug mode:

> http://wiki.caucho.com/IDE#Remote_Debugging

After that connect your eclipse to the server by choosing debug configuration -> new remote java application (in which you will need to insert the address and the port of the server.

This concept is valid to pretty much all type of servers.

Comment: I haven't had time to implement this yet, but I looked at the link, and it seems to be what I was looking for, so I am flagging this post as the answer for now